# Error in object declaration when inheritance is used

Tags: php, oop, class, constructor

I have been using three classes. Two classes extends the third class db. But the problem is when I declare objects of these classes the second object is created as  clone of the first object. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
        class db extends PDO {
    public function __construct() {
            echo "DB constructor called\n";
            ..
    }
        class Admin extends db {
        private $uid, $username, $password, $level, $name, $email;
    public function __construct() {
            echo "Admin constructor called\n";
            parent::__construct();

}
        class Movie extends db {
        private $mid, $title, $slug;
    public function __construct() {
            echo "Movie constructor called\n";
            parent::__construct();
}
```

---

```
$base_path = "../../";

require $base_path . 'config.php';
require $base_path . 'lib/class.db.php';
require $base_path . 'lib/Admin.php';
require $base_path . 'lib/Movie.php';

$adminObj = new Admin();
$movieObj = new Movie();
var_dump($adminObj);
var_dump($movieObj);
```

---

Output is

```
Admin constructor called
DB constructor called
Movie constructor called
DB constructor called
object(Admin)#1 (11) {
  ["uid":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["username":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["password":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["level":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["name":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["email":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["error":"db":private]=>
  NULL
  ["sql":"db":private]=>
  NULL
  ["bind":"db":private]=>
  NULL
  ["errorCallbackFunction":"db":private]=>
  NULL
  ["errorMsgFormat":"db":private]=>
  NULL
}
object(Admin)#2 (11) {
  ["uid":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["username":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["password":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["level":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["name":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["email":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["error":"db":private]=>
  NULL
  ["sql":"db":private]=>
  NULL
  ["bind":"db":private]=>
  NULL
  ["errorCallbackFunction":"db":private]=>
  NULL
  ["errorMsgFormat":"db":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

---

Modified code, please analyse this. When the parent::__construct($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $options); in the db class is removed the issue will disappear.

```
<?php
/** The Database Driver */
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');

/** The name of the database */
define('DB_NAME', 'sample');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

class db extends PDO
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "DB constructor called\n";
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        $dsn = DB_DRIVER . ":host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME;
        parent::__construct($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $options);
    }
}

class Admin extends db
{
    private $uid, $username, $password, $level, $name, $email;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Admin constructor called\n";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Movie extends db
{
    private $mid, $title, $slug;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Movie constructor called\n";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}


$adminObj = new Admin();
$movieObj = new Movie();
var_dump($adminObj);
var_dump($movieObj);
?>
```

Comment: Can you recreate this problem with a smaller system. I would like to work on it, but I dont have much free time lately. If you can observe the problem in a smaller system, then it is definitely a bug. Since the entire code is not here I cannot be sure.

Comment: @cem-kalyoncu Thanks for showing interest in my issue. I ll recreate the situation in a smaller system and update here. Please wait.

Comment: @Cem Kalyoncu I have placed the smaller code with same issue at http://stackoverflow.com/q/6310058/493796. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no problems at all -- the output is exactly as expected. So it must be an error somewhere else in the files you are including. Here is the **standalone** test code:

```
<?php
class db extends PDO
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "DB constructor called\n";
    }
}

class Admin extends db
{
    private $uid, $username, $password, $level, $name, $email;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Admin constructor called\n";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Movie extends db
{
    private $mid, $title, $slug;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Movie constructor called\n";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}


$adminObj = new Admin();
$movieObj = new Movie();
var_dump($adminObj);
var_dump($movieObj);
```

And this is the output:

```
Admin constructor called
DB constructor called
Movie constructor called
DB constructor called
object(Admin)#1 (6) {
  ["uid":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["username":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["password":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["level":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["name":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["email":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
}
object(Movie)#2 (3) {
  ["mid":"Movie":private]=>
  NULL
  ["title":"Movie":private]=>
  NULL
  ["slug":"Movie":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

So please check your actual code. Maybe (just maybe) you are including the wrong file .. or the 2nd class got declared in another place (and you may be editing wrong file)...

**EDIT:**
Alex, thank you for providing more info. I have ound the problem in your updated code: `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true`, -- change `true` to `false` and see the difference :)

Comment: I have added the modified code in the question with respect to you test code. Please check that.

Comment: @Alex: Found the problem in your updated code: `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,` -- change it to `false` and see the difference :). P.S. -- I'm sure you will find the documentation about this attribute yourself.

Answer (score 0):

They are not clones. They are both inheriting from the db class, and you haven't done any changes to them. They are not clones - they are simply identical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent 2 PDO instances, use [Singleton pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php)

Comment: Utilizing Dependency Injection pattern or Service Locator one would be much better.