# Error in object declaration when PDO class is extended

Tags: php, oop, class, inheritance, pdo

I have create three classes. One class is db which extends from PDO. Other two class extends from the db class. But the problem is when I initialize objects of these sub classes the second object is created as clone of the first object. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<?php
/** The Database Driver */
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');

/** The name of the database */
define('DB_NAME', 'sample');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

class db extends PDO
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "DB constructor called\n";
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        $dsn = DB_DRIVER . ":host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME;
        parent::__construct($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $options);
    }
}

class Admin extends db
{
    private $uid, $username, $password, $level, $name, $email;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Admin constructor called\n";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Movie extends db
{
    private $mid, $title, $slug;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Movie constructor called\n";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}


$adminObj = new Admin();
$movieObj = new Movie();
var_dump($adminObj);
var_dump($movieObj);
?>
```

---

Here is the output of the above. **Please note the type of objects** shown in the output.

```
Admin constructor called
DB constructor called
Movie constructor called
DB constructor called
object(Admin)#1 (6) {
  ["uid":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["username":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["password":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["level":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["name":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["email":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
}
object(Admin)#2 (6) {
  ["uid":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["username":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["password":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["level":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["name":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
  ["email":"Admin":private]=>
  NULL
```

}

---

When the parent::__construct($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $options); in the db class is removed the issue will disappear.

Comment: If you are unhappy with the proposed solution & need persistent connections, then (well, I would suggest it in any case) do not extend PDO at all and create PDO instance inside your `db` class instead or pass PDO instance as a parameter to Admin/Movie class constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You have `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,` and you are attempting to create 2 PDO objects with the same DSN string. This tells PDO to return already established connection when you do `$movieObj = new Movie();` instead of creating new one.

Solution in your case:
`PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,`

Useful link: [Connections and Connection management](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

> When the parent::__construct($dsn,
> DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $options); in
> the db class is removed the issue will
> disappear.
> Yes, because the actual PDO object will not be created in this case.

Comment: While this is a correct answer, it only works around the PHP bug. This will cause there to be one connection per object which is a waste, and it will prevent any persistent connections from being used across requests (which might be desired).

Comment: I'm completely agree about "persistent connections" thing. The best way would be not to extend PDO **at all** but to work with PDO directly (as a db handler) and have db class declared with no "extends" (e.g. `class db { ... }`) with PDO object as a class field (created in __construct() or passed as parameter etc).

Answer (score 0):

First off, this seems like a bug, and it's probably due to how the PDO class internally handles persistent connections. That is, PHP shouldn't return the wrong extended class, but probably is because the core PDO driver was not designed with extending it in mind.

I searched for bugs on bugs.php.net, and there are some listed. (e.g., search for "pdo extend persistent") See [#47407](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47407) for something similar.

All that said, it seems like a bad design on your part. Your classes should take a handle to an existing PDO object:

```
$db = new DB();
$movie = new Movie($db);
```

This will work around the PHP bug, but just as important... it's better designed.

Comment: I guess this is NOT a bug but rather have a look at [this explanation](http://www.selfcontained.us/2011/04/20/php-and-an-abstract-singleton/).